# Eclipse RCP: programmatically associate file type with Editor?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, editor, eclipse-rcp, file-association

**How programmatically associate file type with Editor?**

That is what Eclipse-RCP Java code can do what is archived with the following UI interaction:

```
Window -> Preferences
General -> Editors -> File Associations
Add... > File type: *.json
Select *.json file type 
Add... (Associated editors) > JavaScript Editor
Make it default
```

Ralated to Q
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12429221/eclipse-file-associations-determine-which-editor-in-list-of-associated-editors
[Eclipse: associate an editor with a content type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5859641/eclipse-associate-an-editor-with-a-content-type)
[Get associated file extensions for an Eclipse editor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10052864/get-associated-file-extensions-for-an-eclipse-editor)
[Opening a default editor, on a treeviewer selection eclipse rcp(eg: as eclipse knows that j.java files must be opened in text editor)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14374921/opening-a-default-editor-on-a-treeviewer-selection-eclipse-rcpeg-as-eclipse-k)

[eclipse rcp change icon for xml configuration file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11483161/eclipse-rcp-change-icon-for-xml-configuration-file)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I know your questions says "programmatically" but I'll give a complete run down of the methods.

If you are writing the plugin that provides the editor, then you should simply declare the extension in your plugin.xml.

```
   <extension
         point="org.eclipse.ui.editors">
      <editor
            ...
            extensions="json"
            ...
```

If you are distributing a complete RPC application, you can edit the plugin.xml for the plugin that provides the editor or add a plugin that just refers to that editor.

But, *if* you have to do it programmatically, you are manipulating the internals of an RPC instance. Eclipse does not provide a public API for that but this code will do it:

```
            // error handling is omitted for brevity
    String extension = "json";
    String editorId = "theplugin.editors.TheEditor";

    EditorRegistry editorReg = (EditorRegistry)PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getEditorRegistry();
    EditorDescriptor editor = (EditorDescriptor) editorReg.findEditor(editorId);
    FileEditorMapping mapping = new FileEditorMapping(extension);
    mapping.addEditor(editor);
    mapping.setDefaultEditor(editor);

    IFileEditorMapping[] mappings = editorReg.getFileEditorMappings();
    FileEditorMapping[] newMappings = new FileEditorMapping[mappings.length+1];
    for (int i = 0; i < mappings.length; i++) {
        newMappings[i] = (FileEditorMapping) mappings[i];
    }
    newMappings[mappings.length] = mapping;
    editorReg.setFileEditorMappings(newMappings);
```

Answer (score 1):

Associating file type means associating content of ur editor with a predefined one.
This can be easily achieved via plugin.xml..
Just follow the following link:-

Eclipse help Documentation

http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp

and search for  org.eclipse.core.contenttype.contentTypes.

Comment: ContentType may be too complicated option http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Fguide%2Fruntime_content_contributing.htm&cp=2_0_3_4_1