# Eclipse plug-in: Custom plugin.xml like editor

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, plugin.xml

I've been trying to mimic the `plugin.xml` editor in my own Eclipse plug-in. I want a graphical editor for a custom file type. The same way in which PDE has a specific form/editor to open `plugin.xml`.

From what I understand I can implement a text `Editor` and link a file type to open in a particular editor. To add a graphical aspect I can make a `Form`.

What I don't understand is how to link this `Form` to my custom file type.

Comment: Maybe this could be helpful, there is a similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15877123/eclipse-rcp-programmatically-associate-file-type-with-editor .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `FormEditor` for this (`org.eclipse.ui.forms.editor.FormEditor`). This extends the more basic `MultiPageEditorPart`.

`FormEditor` supports multiple pages, these can be form based using the `FormPage` class, or based on an ordinary text editor, or even just an arbitary set of SWT controls. So this allows you to have a arrangement like the plugin.xml editor (which is a `FormEditor`).

Answer (score 1):

I would try adding the following two entries in your `plugin.xml` file:

Firstly, add a `contentType` plugin extension, where you specify the `file extension`:

[image]

Then, as you said, you need to implement the editor. Add an `editors` plugin, in which you implement your editor. Don't forget to enable the `default` option:

[image]

After that, add a new `contentTypeBinding` subnode to the edior. There you need to use the id of the content type:

[image]

Also, do not forget to add the view in your perspective.

[image]

P.S. I have tested this just now with a simple `TextEditor`, and it should work:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I was looking for implementing a graphical editor. Found out that using `MultiPageEditorPart` instead of `TextEditor` will do the trick.